# Ionic Cordova not building android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.

```
    ng.cmd run app:ionic-cordova-build --platform=android exited with exit code 3.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

```
   

         ionic:lib Terminal info: { ci: false, shell: 'C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe', tty: true, windows: true } +0ms
      ionic:lib CLI global options: { _: [ 'cordova', 'build', 'android' ], help: null, h: null, verbose: true, quiet: null, interactive: true, color: true, confirm: null, json: null, project: null, '--': [] } +4ms
      ionic:lib:project Project type from config: @ionic/angular (angular) +0ms
      ionic:lib:project Project details: { configPath: 'E:\\Mobile Apps\\starapp\\ionic.config.json', errors: [], context: 'app', type: 'angular' } +0ms
      ionic Context: { binPath: 'C:\\Users\\Muhammad Islam\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\ionic\\bin\\ionic', libPath: 'C:\\Users\\Muhammad Islam\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\ionic', execPath: 'E:\\Mobile Apps\\starapp', version: '5.4.16' } +0ms
      ionic:lib:integrations:cordova:config Loading Cordova Config (config.xml: 'E:\\Mobile Apps\\starapp\\config.xml', package.json: 'E:\\Mobile Apps\\starapp\\package.json') +0ms
      ionic:lib:build build options: {
      ionic:lib:build   '--': [],
      ionic:lib:build   engine: 'cordova',
      ionic:lib:build   platform: 'android',
      ionic:lib:build   project: undefined,
      ionic:lib:build   verbose: false,
      ionic:lib:build   configuration: undefined,
      ionic:lib:build   sourcemaps: undefined,
      ionic:lib:build   cordovaAssets: true,
      ionic:lib:build   watch: undefined,
      ionic:lib:build   type: 'angular'
      ionic:lib:build } +0ms
      ionic:lib:telemetry Sending telemetry for command: 'ionic cordova build' [ 'android', '--verbose', '--interactive', '--color' ] +0ms
      ionic:lib:hooks Looking for ionic:build:before npm script. +0ms
      ionic:lib:build Looking for ionic:build npm script. +14ms
    > ng.cmd run app:ionic-cordova-build --platform=android
      ng:analytics getGlobalAnalytics +0ms
      ng:analytics Client Analytics config found: null +3ms
      ng:analytics Analytics settings not found. Ignoring all analytics. +1ms
      ng:analytics getSharedAnalytics +1ms
    Option "lazy" is deprecated: Use 'inject' option with 'false' value instead.
    [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.
    
            ng.cmd run app:ionic-cordova-build --platform=android exited with exit code 3.
    
            Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
      ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: 'process.exit' received +0ms
      ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: running 1 functions +1ms
      ionic:utils-process error while killing process tree for 14900: Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 14900 /T /F
      ionic:utils-process ERROR: The process "14900" not found.
      ionic:utils-process 
      ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:390:12)
      ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
      ionic:utils-process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
      ionic:utils-process     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5) {
      ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
      ionic:utils-process   code: 128,
      ionic:utils-process   signal: null,
      ionic:utils-process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 14900 /T /F'
      ionic:utils-process } +133ms
      ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: error from function: Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 14900 /T /F
      ionic:utils-process ERROR: The process "14900" not found.
      ionic:utils-process 
      ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:390:12)
      ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
      ionic:utils-process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
      ionic:utils-process     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5) {
      ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
      ionic:utils-process   code: 128,
      ionic:utils-process   signal: null,
      ionic:utils-process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 14900 /T /F'
      ionic:utils-process } +4ms
      ionic:utils-process processExit: exiting (exit code: 3) +3ms
```

Comment: Please run the cordova build command with --verbose, and add the info to your question

Comment: I have done it. Please check it out.

Comment: do you have `es5BrowserSupport` in your angular.json file?

Comment: No, I didn't find any package like this

Answer (score 0):

you added some deprecated plugin so you getting this error first check that and replace with new one .

that solve your problem.